# Javascript countdown not working for php loop

Tags: php, javascript, loops, timer, countdown

Hello i me and a friend have a maffia game. I have a countdown timer code but it only works when i use one timer. But i need to use it in a loop to get more timers in a table. I searched on google but nothing really helped. I saw that i had to use different id's but that didn't work for me. I have little knowledge of javascript.

This are my codes:

While loop:

```
while($info = mysql_fetch_object($dbres))
{
$j = 0;
$bieding = mysql_fetch_object(mysql_query("SELECT `bedrag` FROM `biedingen` WHERE `veilingid`='{$info->id}' ORDER BY `bedrag` DESC LIMIT 1"));
$tijd = ($info->tijd + $info->duur * 60 * 60 - $time);
echo '<tr>
<td>'.veilingnaam($info->id,1,1).'</td>
<td>'.usernaam($info->veiler,1,1).'</td>
<td>&euro;'.getal($bieding->bedrag).'</td>
<td><div id="teller'.$j.'"></div></td>
</tr>';
}
```

Javascript part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var seconds = <?= ($tijd+1) ?>;
var countdown = document.all? document.all["teller<?= $j?>"] : document.getElementById?         document.getElementById("teller<?= $j?>") : "";
var woord = "seconden";
function display()
{
seconds=seconds-1;
if(seconds==1){ woord="seconde"; }
if(seconds==0){ woord="seconden"; }
if(seconds<0)
{
    self.location.replace(self.location);
}
else
{
    if (countdown)
    {
        countdown.innerHTML=seconds+" "+woord;
        setTimeout('display()',1000);
    }
}
}
display();
</script>
```

Comment: Minor remark: don't write code in native language, it gets hard to share with people [this question is a proof].

Comment: I don't speak your language, so the question is a little hard to understand, but I believe it might help you to look up the documentation for `setInterval` for continuous timed execution as an alternative to a single `setTimeout`

Comment: Also, obligatory: Don't use `mysql_query`, it's deprecated, for reasons that you can see right here, where it allows you to simply create a sql-injectable script...  Learn how to use PDO instead.

Comment: Are you called the javascript after the php script? and make sure the script runs after the 
$(document).ready()function(){
};

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop goes through table rows in a DB, but your JavaScript code is not part of that loop. That means you generate a HTML table for each row, but then you create `<script>...</script>` which includes `$tijd`/`$j` only for the last row (assuming that your `while` executes before the script is added to the page.

Possible workarounds:

- Add a jQuery's selector, something like `$("div.teller").each(function(){...});` and in that function create a timer and/or any other JavaScript code you need associated with that `div`.
  Note that this requires your `div` to get a CSS class "teller".
- Create all JavaScript code that is needed for each DB's table row inside the PHP's `while` loop, but this would probably get really messy.

Also, I advise you to take a look at JavaScript's `setInterval()`, since it is more appropriate than `setTimeout()` for what you want to do.

Another thing to consider: all your timers would have a one second tick. It seems to me that it is better to have a single timer and just keep numbers of seconds (whatever that might be) in a JavaScript array (this one is easily created in PHP's `while` loop).

**Edit:** Here is one way to do this:

```
$data = array();
while($info = mysql_fetch_object($dbres))
{
    ... /* your current code */
    $data[] = "{ id: 'teller$j', seconds: $tijd }";
}
$data = "[ ".implode(", ", $data)." ]";
```

Now, create your JavaScript code **outside** of the loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo $data; ?>; // It is not advisable to use <?= ... ?>
// Get references to divs via saved ids (seconds are already saved
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    data.div = document.getElementById(data.id); // No need for document.all; IE supports getElementById since version 5.5
...
</script>
```

Now, adapt `display()` to work with the elements of your `data` array.

Comment: Is it possible to explain it further more? I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: Let's say your table has 3 rows. So, you want 3 counters/timers, right? But, your JavaScript code executes only once. Open your page in a browser (from a localhost, not directly from disk) and view the source. You'll see what PHP has generated. Check your `<script>...</script>` and it should be clearer. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Okay, i have 2 rows in my database. When i look at the source in browser i see the 2 rows with 2 script sources but the 2nd one is fully ignored.

Comment: So, your `<script>...</script>` is also in some PHP's loop? You didn't mention that before. However, check your IDs. If I'm not mistaken, I'd expect them both to be `teller<the_same_number>` and this is why it doesn't work. You need the JavaScript code for each ID.

Comment: Okey now i managed to make it so every loop the id changes. eg. id=teller0 to id=teller1. But now the time ticks away from the last timer and not from the first.

Comment: You have only one variable `seconds`. You can make one for each row, you can make an array of seconds,... But I think it'd be better that you take a good look now, see what you've learned about your code, reread my answer, and try to redesign your code. Not all JavaScript code needs to be repeated for each row. Basically, you need an array of objects, each holding a reference to `div` and a number of seconds. Once you make that array, the rest of the code can than traverse through that array, which should be both efficient and easy to maintain.

Comment: Take a look at the answer now. I hope the last edit makes the idea more clear.

Comment: Okay well, i learned more about it today. But it's very hard for me. I will take a look what you said and i hope i will find an answer. Thanks alot

Comment: How can i adapt de display() with the elements of the data. Because i don't understand what you mean?